# I cannot unzip.tgz file in my external hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, tar, unzip

I tried to unzip my .tgz file in external hard drive (directory: `/mnt/e`) with

```
tar -xvzf (filename).tgz
```

It failed with error message:

```
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

Also, I saw a suggestion that "removing `-v` option will solve this problem."

So, I tried

```
tar -xzf (filename).tgz
```

Then, It failed with error message:

```
Operation not permitted
```

I tried

```
sudo tar -xzf (filename).tgz
```

or

```
sudo tar -xvzf (filename).tgz
```

with root account.
It still has same error.

However, I tried `unzip` in my my internal drive (`C` drive). Unzip was successfully done.
Why can't I unzip in my external hard drive?

Comment: I have this same issue. I have full read/write/execute permissions on the usb hard drive, but if I want to extract any archive files I have to first copy them to my home folder to extract for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Extract to your external drive with `--directory` (or `-C`) option.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However, I tried it and i have same "operation not permitted" problem...

Comment: 1. Are you able to untar (not unzip) in your hard drive (C)? 2. Are you sure your external drive is mounted? 3. Please copy and paste your command and the full response in here.